# Partly blocked PVC pipe

Tags: repair

Is there any chemical to remove excess solvent that is partly blocking water flow in 3/4 inch PVC pipe ? (the exact location of the restriction/restrictions is not known)

Comment: "Solvent"? What does that mean, exactly? Did you mean pipe cement?

Comment: I cannot think of a way that pipe cement could be blocking a pipe.  Is it a very small diameter pipe?  Was pipe cement poured into an elbow fitting?

Answer (score 1):

"Shoving " anything solid into a PVC pipe is an almost sure way of breaking it. I have come across a few cases similar and usually found the most economical way is to cut out the area that is blocked and replace with new PVC or PEX. I would recommend this even if it means replacing some wallboard.

Answer (score 0):

**No, there is not.**

Any chemical that would to that would also dissolve the pipe. Cut back until you find/remove the restriction and then replumb it properly.

Comment: If pipe is straight, you can sometimes shove a long rod or flexible thing down there to crack out the blockage. Depends on your setup.

Comment: But you'd need to know where it was partly plugged for that.

Comment: A hand auger will usually knock the glue film out. Usually the blockage is quite thin for the problems it causes.